# Swift: Multiple Parse Query from one class

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift3

I have a Parse Class named friendRequest where keys are requestFrom & requestTo which contains unique ids of people who have sent request and received them respectively.

I have a user for whom I need to fetch friend requests which have been sent to him and received by him to find out the status of the request.
I am trying to combine two queries where I match the user's id in requestFrom & requestTo keys and fetch all the results where the condition is true. I get 0 values in return.

My code is:

```
let friendsQuery : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "friendRequest")
let objectId = PFUser.current()?.objectId
friendsQuery.whereKey("requestFrom", equalTo: objectId!)
friendsQuery.whereKey("requestTo", equalTo: objectId!)
friendsQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
    //code
})
```

How should I combine the queries to get the desired results?

Comment: What are "requestFrom" & "requestTo" from parse dashboard? pointers or just String holding objectId of user.

If they are objectPointers try passing PFUser.current() instead of objectId

Comment: They are just string holding objectId of the users. Do you think the query I am using is correct?

Comment: Yes, so you are trying to fetch the request made by and made to current user? That should work